# How to add sql view in setup file of joomla component

Tags: mysql, joomla, jcomponent, sql-view

I am developing a joomla component.
I need to import a sql view in my project.

create view `view_name` as select * from `my_table`

Comment: What is your problem...

Comment: View is not created after install component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you tried in your xml file add something like

```
<install>
        <sql>
            <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">install.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </install>
<uninstall>
        <sql>
            <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">uninstall.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </uninstall>
```

And the install.sql file should have the query.
Also make sure the DB user have permission to add new tables.

Its Done!

Comment: Thanks for answer. all table successfully import in data base but view not imported! i guess my db not permission to install view, but i am not sure! Moreover, i don know is my view code is correct or not, in `phpmyadmin` it work true but by installing component not work. Thanks agian.

Comment: check for the DB permission that is the only possibility if its works fine on phpmyadmin